# FFMPEG Drag and Drop sh file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, sh

On Windows I have a simple batch file which I drop video files onto to convert to webms, it saves a lot of time as I prefer to just use the same configuration and don't care much about the names.

```
@echo off 
echo. 
ffmpeg -i %1 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -quality good -cpu-used 2 -b:v 5000k -qmin 15 -qmax 45 -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1500k -framerate 60 -threads 8 -vf scale=-1:1080 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 192k -f webm %1.webm 
pause
```

I know the .bat file won't really work in Linux (I'm on pop os so pretty much Ubuntu) so with the other lines removed and the `%1` changed to `$1` it works. It won't do anything if I try dragging and dropping a video file onto it though.

I can type sudo then drag and drop the .sh file followed by a video into a terminal and press enter and it will have the same effect as dragging a video file onto a bat file in Windows.

Is there a way to recreate dragging and dropping a file directly onto another and it executing in Linux or is the terminal the only way?

Comment: Which **WM/DE** and **file manager** are you using?  It will depend on these how this can be implemented.

Comment: I'm still using the defaults for Pop OS so I believe its gnome, so GDM and Nautilus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ... for me something like this works:

Create a desktop file, e.g. `shell.desktop`. That needs to look something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=simple
Exec=/bin/bash -c "echo %F; sleep 10"   # obviously this is where your ffmpeg incantation goes
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=gvim
Categories=Utility;
StartupNotify=false
```

That is now a drop target - voila. Mine just echoes back the path of the file dropped.

Comment: That's got it there, thank you very much.
Nautilus seems to not like it so with the use of a different file manager and your .desktop file it works perfectly, cheers again!